# Java - Pass Class as Parameter for Comparison

Tags: java, class

Essentially what I want to do is pass a class as a parameter so that I can preform an `instanceof` comparison.

```
public class MyClass
{
    Object o = something;

    public void myMethod(Class c)
    {
        if(o instanceof c)
        {
            do something
        }
    }
}
```

Where the parameter `Class c` is any class that I choose to pass in from else where. Essentially I want to be able to pass in any class and make a comparison.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can pass any class in that method. Because right now the method only accepts objects of type Class. I think you should pass an Object because it's the root of all classes.

Comment: When I say Class c I mean essentially any class. It could be a String, Integer, or a custom class.

Comment: thats why you should pass an Object. Eduardo has the answer for you.

Comment: You may need to look at your design a bit closer. While it is occasionally necessary, using `instanceof` in this manner is usually a red flag. Overloading methods and generics are often enough, and a better choice when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`Class#isInstance(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)):

```
if(c.isInstance(o)) {
```

> Determines if the specified `Object` is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this `Class`. *This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator*.

Comment: He wants to pass any type of class inside the parameter. This is not a solution.

Comment: @Mnemonics The OP wants to pass a `Class` object, not an instance of an object. These are two different things.

Comment: Actually this worked exactly the way that I want. The quick response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the method accept `Object`. In Java all classes extend from `Object`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    Object o = something;

    public void myMethod(Object c)
    {
        if(o.isInstance(c))
        {
            do something
        }
    }
}
```